# virtual machine cannot be found

Tags: vmware-esxi

After powering down a VM and getting now when trying to start it:

[image]

No config change was made beside that the option to boot in to BIOS was selected. .vmdk .vmx .nvram file are all present, I've checked the paths and everything is on it's place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I would check your permissions - also check to make sure the VM isn't in a folder with a different set of permissions that may be causing this.

View [this link here](http://www.itechlounge.net/2016/03/vmware-power-on-virtual-machine-cannot-be-found/) for a solution I found to the same issue.